# Monodroid: Unsigned Binary upload to Amazon

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mono, unsigned, amazon-appstore

In order to upload an Android app which uses the Google APIs (maps) `Amazon` requires that you upload an `unsigned binary`.

From the Amazon App Management portal:

```
7.       Upload your unsigned binary (shown as Step 1. Upload unsigned binary)
```

Using `MonoDevelop` and `Mono for Android`, how do I create an `unsigned binary` for Amazon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you deploy to an emulator or device, both a signed and unsigned package is created.  Check in bin\Release to find a pair of files like:

- AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1.apk
- AndroidApplication1.AndroidApplication1-Signed.apk

The one without "Signed" is the unsigned package.